# bootstrap modal is not a function

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap modal dialog.
And it works fine while only opening it with

```
<a class="btn" data-controls-modal="my-modal" >Launch Modal</a>
```

But when I try something like

```
$('#close_popup').click(function(){
    $('#rules').modal('toggle');    
});
```

I get a javascript error:

> bootstrap modal is not a function

Moreover. As far a I understand link with `.close` must close the window and it doesn't.
What do I do wrong?

Comment: Have you included the bootstrap-modal.js ?

Comment: sure I did
otherwise popup wouldn't work at all

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I don't know if you have figured out this issue or not being it was a couple months ago when you asked the question, but I came across the same problem and it had to do with a conflict with another plugin, so I will post the solution for future inquiries.

Here is an example of what I did to get around this issue.

```
function ShowImageInModal(path) {
    jQuery.noConflict();
    (function ($) {
        $('#modalImage').removeAttr("src").attr("src", path);
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
    )(jQuery);
}
```

Comment: +1 on this. All I needed to add was *jQuery.noConflict()* before *$('#myModal').modal('show')* Thanks.

Comment: can confirm with @conor; jQuery.noConflict() before the call to .modal('show') fixed the problem in both Chrome and Firefox and got rid of an ugly workaround

Comment: @Etch Thanks alot, adding the JQuery.noConflict() before the line worked for me too.

Comment: Hi i was having the same problem, and i added jQuery.noConflict() before call modal, but when i call a modal, the jquery autocomplete plugin doesn't work.

Answer (score 12):

probably a namespace conflict, simply do this...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are not loading multiple jquery files from multiple locations, local or remote.

Answer (score 2):

one of the most concise ways to avoid these conflicts is :

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="prototype.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(function($){
// Your jQuery code here, using the $
});
</script>
```

as shown in :

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Answer (score 1):

Add `jQuery.noConflict()` inside `$(document).ready(function(){})` can be helping too.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery.noConflict();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#rules').modal('toggle');
```

Is 'rules' is the id of your modal?? because we can use .modal methods only with the div which has the 'modal' class.

and you given that

```
<a class="btn" data-controls-modal="my-modal" >Launch Modal</a>
```

this is working fine and in this you have use 'my-modal' id for the modal.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by removing the following code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Feed Selection</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <!--    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>    -->
                <button type="button" id="feedsave" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which means bootbox somehow conflicts with the bootstrap modal popup.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have bootstrap.js.min loaded in my head tag in the html.

I added the reference to the script and that resolved the issue.