# Failure invoking a modal window through jquery in Yii

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, yii, modal-dialog, yii-booster

I tried to add modal window to my yii app.
For this I use jquery from the framework.
Yet, It does not work with jquery (1.8.3) from the framework: **framework/web/js/source** 
The error is: 
 *Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'modal'* 
 In this line:

```
$('#dataModal').modal().css({
            width: 'auto',
            height: 'auto',
    });
```

(see the full code below).  
The same happens when I exchange modal() to dialog().

Yet, when I try to upload the latest jquery (1.10.2) through googleapis by registering it as a client script, it works (only one time at each view call though):
**config/main.php:**

```
'components'=>array(
...
 'clientScript'=>array(
    'packages'=>array(
        'jquery'=>array(
            'baseUrl'=>'//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/',
            'js'=>array('jquery.min.js'),
        ),
    ),
 ),
```

and register it in the view:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery');
```

The full code pertaining to the case is here:

```
<!-- modal window -->      
<?php $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbModal', 
    array('id'=>'dataModal')); ?>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
        <h4><?=Yii::t("ui", "Выберите номенклатуру")?></h4>
        <!--?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
            'label'=>Yii::t("ui", "Справочник номенклатуры"),
            'url'=>$this->createUrl('assortment/index'),            
            'htmlOptions'=>array('data-dismiss'=>'modal', 'class' => 'btn btn-medium btn-primary', /*'style'=>'float:right; clear:both;'*/),
        )); ?-->
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body"></div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
            'label'=>Yii::t("ui", "Справочник номенклатуры"),
            'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('assortment/index'),           
            'htmlOptions'=>array(/*'data-dismiss'=>'modal',*/ 'class' => 'btn btn-medium btn-primary', 'style'=>'float:left; /*clear:both;*/'),
        )); 
        $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
            'label'=>Yii::t("ui", "Отмена"),
            'url'=>'#',
            'htmlOptions'=>array('data-dismiss'=>'modal'),
        )); ?>
    </div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
<!-- modal end --> 
 ...
<script type="text/javascript">
// this function calls the modal thru AJAX
$('#data-select-btn').click(function(){
   var buttn = this; 
   // $(buttn).button('loading'); 
    $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo $this->createAbsoluteUrl('order/loadData') ?>", /*LoadDataCheckBox*/
      cache: false,
      data: "type="+$("#Order_type").val(),
      success: function(html){
        $(".modal-body").html(html);       
        //$(buttn).button('reset');
        $('#dataModal').modal().css({
            width: 'auto',
            height: 'auto',
            'margin-top': '-50px',
            'margin-left': function () {
                return -($(this).width() / 2) - 80;
            },
        });
      }          
    });
})
</script>
```

For Jquery-ui these are also included:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/application/assets/6d25656/jui/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/application/assets/6d25656/jui/js/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script>
```

### Update

As far as Yii bootstrap extention I do use it, and in bootstrap.js there is the modal class definition and plugin definition.
This file is being loaded after jquery, yet before jquery-ui, **does sequence matter?**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="/application/assets/7d883f12/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

End of the view file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/application/assets/6d25656/jui/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/application/assets/6d25656/jui/js/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: to use .modal or .dialog, you must also include a reference to the jqueryUI script

Comment: jqueru-ui is also included (see updated at bottom).

Comment: I see you're using the Yii Bootstrap extension, you should probably look there for a missing modal() function. jQueryUi only has a dialog() function.

Comment: @davey, how can i find missing modal() function in bootstrap?

Comment: I took a look at it, is the bootstrap.min.js included on your page somewhere? (although there isn't a model() function as well)

Comment: @davey, see my question update. bootstrap.min.js is not included. It's supposed to appear in production mode.

Comment: What is select2.min.js? That's probably the problem, that bootstrap(.min).js is not included for some reason.

Comment: sorry my typo, @davey, there should be <script type="text/javascript" src="/application/assets/7d883f12/js/bootstrap.js"></script> It's located in extentions' folder, but it gets loaded out from assets folder.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39073/discussion-between-igor-savinkin-and-davey)

Comment: probably  `jQuery.noConflict()` will work for you . Make sure js lib does not conflict see this further http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586306/bootstrap-modal-is-not-a-function

Comment: `jQuery.noConflict()` has not helped...

Answer (score 0):

Try this... In `order/loadData` make sure your renderPartial isn't loading scripts a second time.

```
$this->renderPartial('view_partial', array(
    'model' => $model,
), false, false);
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#renderPartial-detail

Comment: actually the modal window does load some tabled content needing for some more scripts. So there is there: $this->renderPartial('view_partial', array(
    'model' => $model,
), false, **true**);

Answer (score 0):

**The sequence matters.**

You should first load jquery, then jquery-ui, thw bootsttrap.js

Try indicate the position in the registerScript:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery', CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
```

More info here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerScriptFile-detail

And how you are including the jQuery UI?

===EDIT===
Try changing the order of the scripts in the config/main using this:

```
'components'=>array(
...
    'clientScript' => array(
        'coreScriptPosition' => CClientScript::POS_END,
    )
),
```

If nothing work, just disable the autoloding like that:

```
'clientScript' => array(
    'scriptMap'=>array(
        'jquery.js'=>false,
        'jquery.min.js'=>false
    ),
),
```

And load then just like the old days ;)

```
<script src="<?php echo $this->baseURL ?>/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: jQuery-ui as well as jquery are automatically loaded by Yii (all ajax calls performed with them). Bootstrap.js is also supposed to be autoloaded since i've installed Bootstrap ext.

Comment: the Yii loads first (in head section) *jquery.js*, litte down  *bootstrap.js* then at the bottom right **before** </body> tag there go *jquery-ui.min.js*
*jquery-ui-i18n.min.js* and *jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js*

Comment: the thing is that i do not include anything. Yii is smart enough to register all core files in different assets folders (jquery and jquery-ui being in one folder) and register them for each page accordingly. You might try to see this link: [source](view-source:http://blogandtraffic.com/application/index.php?r=order/createorder)

Comment: Is asking for password :(

Comment: in this the page the last button ajusted to dropdown is where modal is attached.

Comment: yes, when i inserted 'coreScriptPosition' => CClientScript::POS_END, all the stuff is at the bottom (inside <body> though). Yet now the debugger tells me **$ is not defined**, looks like jquery is not loaded properly.

Comment: The problem is that the scrips are before the call for the *.js files, try move the <script> tag just before the </body> and change the position of the scripts to CClientScript::POS_HEAD

Comment: So, change the order again, lets see what happens

Comment: ok, i've done it. Positions are like original. (i couldn't move my script to the bottom cause of breadcrumbs, but as down as possible).

Comment: Thank you, Marcos, it doesn't help though. I'll try to reorder scripts' loading according to your sugestion tomorrow (now midnight is coming...)

Comment: Ok, try bring the jquery ui to the head, it still in the end of the file

Comment: actually there is a dateTimePicker using jquery-ui, standing above the <script> in markup order. It normally works...